# Can't login to Wordpress without hitting the Remember Me checkbox. Potential SSL implementation bi-product

Tags: login, ssl

Having trouble logging on to a site we have recently launched.

php 7.35
WP 5.41

Everytime you go to login, the URL changes from `https://example.com/wp-login.php` to `https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://example.com/wp-admin/&reauth=1` with an instance page load. No logs.

You can login by hitting the `remember me` checkbox before logging in. This is not an acceptable solution. I am also unable to find anybody with a similar issue with the `remember me` checkbox.

Everything was fine until we added the SSL on the live environment. We usually add the website to Cloudflare, and then install the `really simple SSL` plugin for mixed content stuff. As soon as we added the really simple SSL snippet to the website's `wp-config.php` i could not log back in. I then removed it, and then it worked, i was able to log back in. We have then removed really simple SSL and the snippet from the `wp-config.php` managed the http redirects from cloudflare. The problem was still persistent.

I have tried removing, and re-generating the SALTs for the site cookies and that did nothing. `SameSite Cookie` plugin settings have been modified and this does not change anything regardless of value defined. Every one of these changes i made sure to purge cache and delete all cookies to multiple browsers.

I have installed the site health plugin, and it is saying:

```
The loopback request to your site failed,this means features relying on them are not currently working as expected.
Error encountered: (0) cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

and

```
The REST API request failed due to an error.
Error: [] cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

We have not had issues with self signed certs historically with cloudflare & WP so i am not sure what to do to fix this issue. **Does anyone have ideas as to what could be causing this login behaviour?**

We are still able to login but we have to hit `remember me`, and my understanding of WP core is very limited so I am not familiar with why the `remember me` would work but not a normal login. I don't have much experience with SSL with Wordpress in General so i might not have all the information you need, please ask me to clarify and I can provide as much information as i can.

Comment: Welcome to Wordpress Dev! and  What is your SSL settings in Cloudflare?

Comment: @NathanielSturtz SSL/TLS encryption mode is Full with `Always use HTTPS` on

Comment: Full or Full (strict)

Comment: Just Full, not Full (Strict).

Comment: Ok, are you hosting it your self? And what plugins do you have enabled?

Comment: The issue was not present until the SSL stuff was added. The DNS swap login was working right away and we could login no problem. Moments later once we added the SSL with letsencrypt and cloudflare we were logged out and couldn't log back in. The plugins that were added during the SSL process were: `SameSite Cookie`, `really simple SSL`.  We couldn't log in at all until we removed the really simple SSL plugin and now we were able to login with the `remember me` checkbox being clicked. 
ACF, ACF Pro, Custom plugins, CF7, go live update URLS, font awesome, SVG support, WP mail SMTP, Yoast.

Comment: It is hosted on AWS, yes we are managing the host. We have similar websites with similar theme and instance setup but yet those instances do not have any self signed cert issues or login reauth issues. I have been comparing instances and I have also tried turning off plugins to determine the issue. I will disable everything here see if that works

Comment: Have you tried this on another network, assuming that you are on the same network with your server?